# Autocomplete textbox not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is my javaScript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#<%=txtCompanyName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "PurchaseOrder.aspx/GetLocationName",
                    data: "{ 'locName':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return { value: item }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

this my textbox

```
<td><div class="ui-widget" style="text-align:left">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" Width="350px" Font-Size ="12px" />
        </div></td>
```

css code

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<string> GetLocationName(string locName)
    {
        List<string> allLocations = new List<string>();

        allLocations.Add("comp1");
        allLocations.Add("comp2");
        allLocations.Add("comp3");
        allLocations.Add("comp4");
        allLocations.Add("comp5");

        return allLocations;
    }
```

I am using above codes to create a autocomplete textbox in asp.net,It's not working in my current project,but in a new project this code works perfectly.

Comment: why txtCompanyName.ClientID in the javascript? where has ClientID come from?

Comment: it comes from textbox ID

Comment: @BugFinder `<%= txtCompanyName.ClientID %>` required because the JS used in ASPX page with default config (the `ClientID` generated using server control placeholder naming convention when `ContentPlaceHolder` used).